# Xamarin form iOS app crashed only in release with 11.2 iOS version

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My app got crashed in release mode with 11.2 iOS version. But app works fine with 10.3.
I googled it and couldn't make it.
I can't figure out that what is the cause of the problem. I have written log and this is what I got in error file.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.AddTaskContinuationComplex (System.Object tc, System.Boolean addBeforeOthers) <0x100b050f0 + 0x00060> in :0 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.AddTaskContinuation (System.Object tc, System.Boolean addBeforeOthers) <0x100b053a0 + 0x000cb> in :0 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SetContinuationForAwait (System.Action continuationAction, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext, System.Boolean flowExecutionContext, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x100b03710 + 0x00167> in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OnCompletedInternal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Action continuation, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext, System.Boolean flowExecutionContext) <0x100b3b4c0 + 0x0004b> in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.UnsafeOnCompleted (System.Action continuation) <0x100b3b230 + 0x00027> in :0 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_gsharedvt_constrained_call (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted[TAwaiter,TStateMachine] (TAwaiter& awaiter, TStateMachine& stateMachine) <0x100ba9570 + 0x0026b> in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x100b38080 + 0x00028> in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_1 (System.Object state) <0x100b3ace0 + 0x00053> in :0 
>     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) <0x100af81b0 + 0x00063> in :0 
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x100af1140 + 0x00193> in :0 
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x100af1100 + 0x0002b> in :0 
>     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x100af8120 + 0x0005b> in :0 
>     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x100af5fa0 + 0x001cb> in :0 
>     at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThreadPoolDispatcher (System.Func`1[TResult] callback) <0x101587fc0 + 0x0003f> in :0 
>     at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x100af7f00 + 0x00087> in :0

Comment: I have used xamarin auth for google login.
App launched successfully and after login to google account it return back to app then app closed.

Comment: Please *edit* your post instead of adding details in comments.

Comment: The stackstrace is of not much use. Could you please add logging to your app in order to find the exact position where the exception occurs?

Comment: Did you write some code in `OpenUrl()`? Maybe it's the problem of your code there, post more details about which line throws exception.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used dynamic variable in login page.

This issue has fixed instead of using dynamic i changed this to model

Refer this [Xamarin Forms App crashing in release mode on iOS but works in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48383006/xamarin-forms-app-crashing-in-release-mode-on-ios-but-works-in-debug-mode?rq=1)